# dynamic for loop

Tags: loops

I'm trying to create a dynamic for loop:

```
\def\forinmacro{{a,b,c,d}}
\iftb{SomeBool}{\def\forinmacro{{a}}}
\foreach \m in \forinmacro {...}
```

Note if I change the last line to

```
\foreach \m in {a,b,c,d} {...}
```

it works.

Unfortunately the comma's seem to screw up the foreach and it gives errors(changing a,b,c,d to a lets it work).

Why is `\def\forinmacro{{a,b,c,d}}` breaking the foreach but `\def\forinmacro{{a}}` not?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Both your instances of `\forinmacro` have only one element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the extra braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xparse, ifthen}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\iftb{m m G{\relax}}{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}
\newboolean{SomeBool}\setboolean{SomeBool}{true}
\iftb{SomeBool}{\def\forinmacro{a}}
\foreach \m in \forinmacro {This is letter : \m\par}
\def\forinmacro{x,y,w,z}
\foreach \m in \forinmacro {This is letter : \m\par}
\end{document}
```